# why are essential states for markov chains important?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

In my lecture notes, are results with respect to essential states in a markov chain are uniquely in finite dimension, in other words, I ve been given another proof for properties I already knew for reccurent states...

That's why now, I don't see why we need essential states.

I understand that beeing essential is less powerful (example of the biased random walk).

> But, is it an important notion in general? What can one do with
>   essential states that one can't with reccurent states?

Comment: What is your definition of "essential state"?

Comment: @Math1000  a state A, that is essential is a state with which every state that is reachable from A reaches also A. I use the definition found on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain in reducibility)

Answer (score 2):

When there are finitely many states, the notions of essential state and recurrent state coincide. Clearly a recurrent state is an essential state (in any Markov chain). If $i$ is an essential state which is not recurrent, then $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{X_n\ne i\}\mid X_0=i \right)>0. $$
Thus there exists a sequence of states $j_n$ with $j_0=i$, $j_n\ne i$, $n\geqslant 1$ such that 
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{X_n=j_n\}\mid X_0=j_0 \right) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty P_{j_{n-1}j_n}>0.
$$
Taking negative logs on both yields
$$
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(P_{j_{n-1}j_n})<\infty,
$$
and thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} P_{j_{n-1}j_n}=1$. Since there are finitely many states, $P_{j_{n-1}j_n}$ can only take finitely many values, and hence
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty} P_{j_{n-1}j_n}=1.
$$
Therefore there exists $N$ such that for every $n\geqslant N$, $P_{j_{n-1}j_n}=1$. It follows that $j_N$ is accessible from $i$ but $i$ is not accessible from $j_N$, contradicting the assumption that $i$ was essential.

Comment: Excuse me, what are you doing here ? the proof with the log is really nice, 
original (for me) way, but what's your purpose here?

Comment: To show that an essential state must be a recurrent state. For assuming otherwise leads to a contradiction, as I have shown.

Comment: reccurent implies essential. We agree. Perhaps I wasn't clear when I was asking for "What can one do with essential states that one can't with reccurent states?" ? Otherwise, what properties have an essential state that a reccurent state does not have.

Comment: Well, take your example of the biased random walk - let $X_n= 1$ with probability $p\ne\frac12$ and $X_n = -1$ with probability $1-p$ be independent random variables and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ with $X_0 = x_0\in\mathbb Z$. Then for all $i\in\mathbb Z$ we have that $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{X_k=j\mid X_0 = i\} \right) > 0 $$ and similarly $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{X_k=i\mid X_0 = j\} \right) > 0. $$ Hence all states are essential. But for $\tau_i = \inf\{n>0:X_n=i\}$, $\mathbb P(\tau_i<\infty\mid X_0=i)<1$, so $i$ is not recurrent.