# For a finite state Markov chain, a state is recurrent iff it is essential

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $P$ be the transition matrix of a Markov chain on a finite state space $\mathscr{X}$. A state $x \in \mathscr{X}$ is called **essential** if for all $y$ such that $x \to y$ it is also true that $y \to x$. For finite chains, a state $x$ is essential if and only if 
$$P_x\{ \tau_x^+ < \infty \} = 1,$$ that is, $x$ is recurrent.

I can see that if a state is essential then it must be recurrent. But how can we show that if $x$ is recurrent then $x$ is essential?

Comment: an indirect argument is easiest -- suppose a path with probability $p \in (0,1]$ from $x\to y$ exists in a finite number of steps (exercise: show the number of steps is at most $n$ if there are only n states), and $x$ is recurrent i.e. a return occurs with probability one.  But if there is no path $y\to x$, then the CDF of a return trip (over say $2n$ iterations) is bounded above by $1-p \lt 1$ which is a contradiction

Comment: I answered this question yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453050/why-are-essential-states-for-markov-chains-important/3498835#3498835